# Can I extract html paragraphs from mysql instead of counting characters?

Tags: php, mysql, html, text-extraction

I'm using this code to extract text from the database and it works well. Can I have it extract only the first or second paragraph instead of counting to 640 characters?

```
$this->data['getshorty'] = utf8_substr(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 0, 640);
```

Comment: How are the paragraphs split? Is each paragraph put into `<p>` tags or are there simply 2 line breaks after the paragraphs (e.g. just hitting the return key twice)? Maybe post an example of a product description.

Comment: Yes paragraph breaks like this:
<p>
<b>Intel Core 2 Duo processor</b></p>
<p>Powered by an Intel Core 2 Duo processor at speeds up to 2.16GHz, the new MacBook is the fastest ever.</p>

Comment: it's hard to parse html in MySQL. I'd recommend that you select the entire field and then process the data using a DOMDocument: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that should work if your paragraphs are in `<p></p>` tags:

```
$fullDescription = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
preg_match('/<p\s*>(.)*<\/p\s*>/isU',$fullDescription,$matches);
$this->data['getshorty'] = $matches[0];
```

Hopefully the regex on the second line makes sense to you, ask if not!

Although parsing HTML with regex is usually considered bad practice, I think for a simple example like this it is fine.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I get this error: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` If I change the matches to 1 the error reads the same except the number changes to 1.

Comment: @Stefan I've just updated the regex in my answer, could you try it again with this new code?